# Using --manifest-path to install a workspace library as an artifact breaks relative file paths

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have an interface library in `python` that basically takes a single problem definition and can pass it off via HTTP to solvers, written in different languages, that we bundle with the `python` repo. One of these solvers is based on [this vrp workspace](https://github.com/reinterpretcat/vrp). In order to do this, we added an extra package for an `actix` server into the workspace with the following structure:

```
vrp
- vrp-api
    - config
        - config.full.json
        - config.telemetry.json
    - src
        - main.rs
    - Cargo.toml
```

Inside `main.py` we reference `config.telemetry.json` as:

```
const BASE_CONFIG_PATH: &str = "./vrp-api/config/config.telemetry.json";
```

During development, we would just launch this server with `cargo run --bin vrp-api --release` and it all worked well. Now we need some way for users of the `python` library to actually use this `rust`-based server. Rather than distribute binaries with the package, we added a couple of CLI commands to the `python` library to download and compile the forked repo.

Compressed down, the process looks like:

```
subprocess.call(
    [
        "git",
        "clone",
        "https://github.com/<company_name>/ds-reinterpretcat-vrp",
        f"{self.base}/rust",
    ]
)

subprocess.call(
    [
        "cargo",
        "build",
        "--manifest-path",
        f"{self.base}/rust/vrp-api/Cargo.toml"
    ]
)
```

And the solver can then be launched with `f'cargo run --bin vrp-api --manifest-path {self.base}/rust/vrp-api/Cargo.toml'`.

The server launches but now `BASE_CONFIG_PATH` is invalid. I found a [similar post](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11043#issuecomment-1242482729) on `cargo` and attempted the proposed fix there, with `export RUSTFLAGS='--remap-path-prefix =rust'` prior to the build but that hasn't worked. There are other similar issues I can find related to `--manifest-path` changing the root path, e.g. [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11007) but I haven't been able to get something functional.

Is there something I'm missing in rectifying the path issue? I'm not very familiar with `rust` so I might have misunderstood the advice in those threads. Alternatively, is there a way I could be cloning and compiling this additional repository that would avoid this issue in the first place?

Comment: Why is config.telemetry.json even distributed with the rust package? Why not include it in the python application?

Comment: @etchesketch that's a fair question and, in the end, we will put it into the HTTP payload. However, it's a large library to wrap and it moves at pace. We can set a lot of generic parameters for now with this config and worry more about the functionality. In any case, it doesn't change the fact that the file paths are being messed up and I would like to understand how to fix that, even if our implementation moves away from it. It's more-generally useful to know